# Netsuite SQL type script generates leading space

Tags: javascript, sql, netsuite

I am combining the contents of two fields to create a URL Component. The problem is that the script seems to yield a leading space in the result. I don't really understand what I have done wrong and I don't understand the logic of the syntax. I have tried the tutorials but they don't seem to help.

This is my script

**LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE({parent}|| '/' || {name},' : ','/'),' ','-'))**

For example:

"parent" might contain "Lighting Components"
"name" might contain "Commercial Bulkheads"

Expected result "lighting-components/commercial-bulkheads"

Actual result   " lighting-components/commercial-bulkheads"

Comment: The SQL formula won't give that result so it must be something else outside of that.  Show the rest of your JavaScript.

Comment: It is a Netsuite workflow, I simply enter the above script and that is the result.